# How can I print the non-filtered values in IntStream in Java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I am really new to the functional programming and these features in Java 8.
I am trying some things with `IntStream`, but I can not do one simple thing: if I filter some array of integers, how can I modify and print out the non-filtered values?

So, for example, if I have an array `[1,2,3,4]` and I filter all the uneven numbers and then add 7 to them, how can I then print all the remaining even numbers? Can this be done in one line of code?

Here is some example code:

```
int[] numbers={1,2,3,4,8,9,6};
IntStream.of(numbers)
    .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
    .map(i -> i + 7)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Your example is doing exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific example you provide, I'd add the conditional element to the `map` operation, as so:

```
IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 6)
    .map(i -> i % 2 != 0 ? i + 7 : i)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Each number `i` gets mapped to `i + 7` if it's odd, or else it remains as is. Once a number has been discarded from the `Stream`, it's gone.

Comment: @Opiatto As an aside, I wouldn't be worried about making things compact or, trying to limit the numbers of lines of code - It's much better to focus on making it clear what you're doing :-)

Answer (score 1):

A quick suggestion would be to log it inside the filter itself.

This could look like this:

```
final int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 6};
IntStream.of(numbers)
    .filter(i -> {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Dropped " + i);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
    .map(i -> i + 7)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This prints the following

```
8
Dropped 2
10
Dropped 4
Dropped 8
16
Dropped 6
```

You can also extract the filter itself inside a constant, e.g.

```
private static final IntPredicate MY_LOGGING_FILTER = x -> {
  if (x % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Dropped " + x);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

to reduce the code to

```
final int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 6};
IntStream.of(numbers)
    .filter(MY_LOGGING_FILTER)
    .map(i -> i + 7)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```